# Any Way to Control Remaining Item on Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-batch

If I have items like this

```
-> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And if ChunkSize =3, **spring batch ItemReader** reads item like

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
[10]
```

But, I want to

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9,10]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i in 1..12) {   // added for testing

  val list = IntArray(i) { it + 1 }.toList()

  val result = list
    .chunked(3)
    .groupBy { it.count() }
    .run {
      values.flatten().run {
        when (keys.size) {
          1    -> this
          else -> dropLast(2).plusElement(takeLast(2).flatten())
        }
      }
    }

  println(result)

}
```

Test output:

```
[[1]]
[[1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: An error with this code: Even if the last chunk is the correct size, it will group the last two. So `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` gives  `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`. This happens because of `.flatMap { it.value }` and then `size` refers to that result, not the initial `groupBy`'s keys' size - which would have been the correct one to check. So `size` refers to the flatMap of values. I _think_ OP wants to merge the last two items only if the last one is smaller than the required size, not every time; which I think you were trying to do as well.

Comment: @aneroid: you're right. Just amended the code to check the size of the last element and if it is not 3, it will concatenate the last two sublists, so that the last sublist is always 3, 4, or 5 elements long (unless the initial list is shorter than 3 of course).

Comment: Yes, working now, as seen in your example output. Also, you don't need the `.groupBy { it.count() }` anymore, since you `.flatMap { it.value }` it's the same thing as the `chunked` result. So just `.chunked(chunkSize)` and then `.run...`. And then the only diffs between our answers is `let vs run`, `if vs when` and `+ listOf vs plusElement`. :-)

Comment: @aneroid: again you're of course right. My solution first used the key of the groupBy later on to determine the chunkSize (without needing to repeat the literal 3 at two places or to introduce a variable like _chunkSize_ above).

Comment: I reconstructed my first solution (the one using _groupBy_).

Comment: Nice one. +1. Was momentarily confused about how you were able to access `keys` from the inner `run` with an implicit `this` but it seems Kotlin is happy to look at the outer level for the matching implicit `this` object which has a `keys` attribute/member. So `keys.size` is okay, but `this.keys.size` is not because then it's the inner run's "this" which is a List of Lists of Ints. Putting `.run outer@` and `this@outer.keys.size` resolves correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the adjustment by checking the size of the last item in the result, and if it's smaller than the `chunkSize`, then append it to the second-last item of the result:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val l = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    val chunkSize = 3
    val c = l.chunked(chunkSize)
        .let {
            println(it)  // basic chunked result
            if (it.size >= 2 && it.last().size < chunkSize)
                it.dropLast(2) + listOf(it.takeLast(2).flatten())
            else
                it
        }
    println(c)
}
```

Output for `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Output for exactly correct ending chunks, with `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`:

```py
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Here's an extension function which does that using generics, so chunking + merging for Iterables of any type:

```kotlin
fun <T> Iterable<T>.chunkedMergeSmall(chunkSize: Int) =
    chunked(chunkSize)
    .let {
        println(it)
        if (it.size >= 2 && it.last().size < chunkSize)
            it.dropLast(2) + listOf(it.takeLast(2).flatten())
        else
            it
    }

// println(list.chunkedMergeSmall(3))
```